# Find probabilistic relationships between multiple signals

Tags: time-series, independence, signal-processing

Suppose that there are a large number of stochastic signals. I want to:

1. Partition them into a set of groups so that different groups are almost independent with each other.
2. Find a small number of key signals within each group so that the other signals can be viewed simple functions (or random functions) of the key signals.

Which branch of statistics or machine learning does this problem belong to? Could anyone give me the "key words" on such problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, to partition, you are looking for principal component analysis or PCA

The second part can also be arrived at by studying factor loadings to determine the primary variables in each factor.